# c++ opencv undistort image by pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, distortion

I have a distorted image, and the calibration data needed to undistort it. I am using openCv, but CANNOT use the undistort function, as the data I have for the distortion coefficients is in a 2 parameter model.
Talking to the camera manufacturer, I have the math required to calculate the undistortion. It looks like this:

```
//calculate the radius
    Point2d pr; //distorted point/pixel
    double dx = (pr.x - ppx);
    double dy = (a * pr.y - a * ppy);

    //calculate the scale factor

    double s = 1 + (pow(vrx, 2) + pow(vry, 4));

    //correct the distortion per point

    Point2d pc; //undistorted point/pixel
    pc.x = ((s * dx) + ppx);
    pc.y= ((s * dy) + ppy) / a;
```

All fine. Now, how do I run this through an openCv Mat image and create a new image from the product?

Should I take the Mat, loop through creating a Point2d from each row/column entry, then convert the resulting points back into a Mat? Or is there a better way?

Thanks all.

Comment: Did you try `remap`?

Comment: I will now. :) Thanks!  Looking at the docs, I am a bit confused. Should I run my code on the map_x and map_y matrices, then run remap? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html

Comment: IIUC, that is how it works. It's a little memory intensive but should get you to a solution fast. But if you need speed or minimal memory consumption you would probably not have chosen OpenCV in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to that camera?